# How can I make my Message Collector listen for messages sent by a mentioned user Discord.js v12

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The title says it all. I've tried changing

```js
const two = message.channel.createMessageCollector(t => t.author.id === message.author.id, {max: 1})
```

to

```js
const two = message.channel.createMessageCollector(t => t.<member>.id === <member>.id, {max: 1})
```

but nothing seems to work. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch the mentioned users, use [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members).

```js
const two = message.channel.createMessageCollector(t => t.author.id === message.mentions.members.first().id, {max: 1})
```